# R ggplot2 overlaid histograms three column data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I've got the following data frame:

```
Triage    v       value
1       OverAll 0.008314562
2       OverAll 0.076387969
3       OverAll 0.593447728
4       OverAll 0.285013913
5       OverAll 0.036835829
1       DidNotWait  NA
2       DidNotWait  0.00252738
3       DidNotWait  0.48272957
4       DidNotWait  0.447346251
5       DidNotWait  0.067396799
```

By using R ggplot I need to overlay two distributions: one for "OverAll" and the other for "did not wait". Then the x axis will be made according to the Triage and the Y axis will have the value.

I'm using this:

```
ggplot(temp, aes(Triage, v)) + 
  geom_histogram(data = subset(temp, temp$v == 'OverAll'), fill = 'blue', alpha = 0.1, ) +  
  geom_histogram(data = subset(temp, temp$v == 'DidNotWait'), fill = 'blue', alpha = 0.1, )
```

But it's not working

Comment: You're looking for a distribution so the x axis shouldn't be specified by another variable. That would be more like a time series. I'd go for something like this `ggplot(temp, aes(value, col=v)) + geom_density()` and as a second option `ggplot(temp, aes(value, fill = v)) + geom_histogram(position = "dodge")`. Note that you provided very few observations (with many decimal points) for the histogram to make sense.

Comment: In case you prefer a time series philosophy use this `ggplot(temp, aes(Triage, value, col=v)) + geom_line()`. Still not convinced you really want the distribution. Maybe you just want to plot `value` over `Triage` :)